# Pass array to Java from Shell Script

Tags: shell-script, java

I have data as below which I want to pass directly to Java main method from shell script at once.

```
1  firstfile.txt   Success
2  secondfile.txt  Failed
3  thirdfile.txt   Success
```

I know I can call java as below where `var1` and `var2` represent just single strings:

```
java $myJava "$var1" "$var2"
```

But is it possible that I pass the data above as arrays to Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a Java array from a shell script via the command line. You can pass a list of strings representing an array.

For example,

```
a=(
    '1  firstfile.txt   Success'
    '2  secondfile.txt  Failed'
    '3  thirdfile.txt   Success'
)

printf "We will pass %d parameters:" ${#a[@]}; printf " '%s'" "${a[@]}"; printf "\n"
java "$myjava" "${a[@]}"
```

Note that in the `We will pass...` statement I have added quotes around the strings to mark out the difference between the parameters and their space separated words. The quote marks are not seen by your Java program.